# React test onChange on input using react shallow-renderer

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-hooks, react-test-renderer

I'm trying to test searchForm component of React with onChange prop.

```
const SearchForm = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState('');

  return (
    <form className={styles.searchForm}>
      <input
        value={value}
        onChange={(e) => setValue(e.target.value)} // test this line
        className={styles.searchForm__input}
      />
      <button type="submit" aria-label="Search" className={styles.searchForm__button} />
    </form>
  );
};
```

Here is example of my test:

```
import React from 'react';
import ShallowRenderer from 'react-test-renderer/shallow';
import SearchForm from '../index';

const setUp = () => {
  const renderer = new ShallowRenderer();
  renderer.render(<SearchForm />);
  return renderer.getRenderOutput();
};

describe('render form component', () => {

  it('handle onChange in form input field', () => {
    const result = setUp();
    expect(result).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

This test passes, but JEST says that this line of code (with onChange) is uncovered.

I found how to launch onChange:

```
result.props.children[0].props.onChange();
```

This launches original prop but i get error on e.target -- cannot read property of undefined.
I feel like i need to mock setValue somehow, but i can't figure out how. I'm new to JEST.
Maybe this may be done with just react-test-renderer in better way.

Comment: `onChange` expects an event as its first parameter; you can create a mock event like `const mockEvent = { target: { value: 'input value' } }` and then use it like `result.props.children[0].props.onChange(mockEvent)`.

Comment: Thank you. But I cant find how to test it properly. Right now i'm testing it like this
 `const mockEv = { target: { value: 't' } };
  result.props.children[0].props.onChange(mockEv);
  expect(result.props.children[0].props.value).toBe('t');`
Test fails because value doesn't change. Though i can use trick and replace 't' with '' in .toBe.
I just want to clarify for myself how to use jest in situations like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution:

`index.tsx`:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

export const SearchForm = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState('');

  return (
    <form>
      <input value={value} onChange={(e) => setValue(e.target.value)} />
      <button type="submit" aria-label="Search" />
    </form>
  );
};
```

`index.test.tsx`:

```
import React from 'react';
import TestRenderer, { act } from 'react-test-renderer';
import ShallowRenderer from 'react-test-renderer/shallow';
import { SearchForm } from './';

describe('66907704', () => {
  it('should handle onChange event', () => {
    const testRenderer = TestRenderer.create(<SearchForm />);
    const testInstance = testRenderer.root;
    expect(testInstance.findByType('input').props.value).toEqual('');
    const mEvent = { target: { value: 'teresa teng' } };
    act(() => {
      testInstance.findByType('input').props.onChange(mEvent);
    });
    expect(testInstance.findByType('input').props.value).toEqual('teresa teng');
  });

  it('should handle onChange event when use shallow render', () => {
    const shallowRenderer = ShallowRenderer.createRenderer();
    shallowRenderer.render(<SearchForm />);
    let tree = shallowRenderer.getRenderOutput();
    let input = tree.props.children[0];
    const mEvent = { target: { value: 'teresa teng' } };
    input.props.onChange(mEvent);
    tree = shallowRenderer.getRenderOutput();
    input = tree.props.children[0];
    expect(input.props.value).toEqual('teresa teng');
  });
});
```

unit test result:

```
 PASS  examples/66907704/index.test.tsx (6.636 s)
  66907704
    ✓ should handle onChange event (10 ms)
    ✓ should handle onChange event when use shallow render (1 ms)

-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File       | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files  |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 index.tsx |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        7.443 s
```

package versions:

```json
"jest": "^26.6.3",
"react": "^16.14.0",
```